# Building html structure in php or javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I've been doing a lot of ajax calls and using the returned data to build html with javascript. However, I've noticed some people are returning the constructed html in the ajax calls since they're doing it all in php.

What is the preferred method? I have a bunch of stuff already using javascript, so I guess I would prefer not changing everything to use just php. But, I'm assuming php would be more "secure."?

The following is what I've been doing:

```
$main_frag = $("<div class='order-container'/>");

$contact_frag = $("<div class='group'><div class='line-data'>Name: "+data.name+"</div><div class='line-data'>Email: "+data.email+"</div><div class='line-data'>Phone: "+data.phone+"</div></div>");

$address_frag = $("<div class='group'><div class='line-data'>Address 1: "+data.address_one+"</div><div class='line-data'>Address 2: "+address2+"</div><div class='line-data'>City: "+data.city+"</div><div class='line-data'>Province: "+data.province+"</div><div class='line-data'>Postal Code: "+data.postal+"</div></div>");
```

etc..

I just want to hear the opinions of the community.

Comment: So you also added jQuery into the mix. That's a third platform. You didn't state your goals. Both methods have advantages and disadvanges, so your question asks for too many possible answers.

Answer (score 0):

Look at some Javascript template solutions, such as Underscore.js (http://underscorejs.org/). Which is just an example, there's many. This should give you more separation and flexibility than just JQuery.

Also for more complex Javascript logic, you should consider to start using some Javascript MVC framework, such as Backbone.js (http://backbonejs.org/). Again there's many.

For browser / server communication, you can use JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that retrieving them in parts or as a whole structure will have difference. both of them can be changed either via MITB ( Man in The Browser ) or even simple using developr tools that let you modify JS and HTML in the Browser..

Answer (score 0):

IMO mustache is a good choice: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/

with mustache you can use templates within your javascript to generate the markup