# Construct html in PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Something similar was asked here: [Building html structure in php or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547884/building-html-structure-in-php-or-javascript)

with no answer. Mine is a bit different. I'm about to start a project where a "big div" on the right side has main content+interaction while the left side has a constantly present menu (not of interest for us). The "big div" on the right changes content through calls like:

```
function calledByButton()
{
     parent.document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=loads something in "big div"
}
```

Now, this content has stuff that needs to be processed before displaying. Do I:

1) Let a php construct the whole html content and dispatch it so the javascript throws that in "big div" (sounds laborious to a noob like me having lotsa "echo (html lines)", but I did it before. Maybe thats the standard and I don't know.)

2) php sends data arrays, javascript interprets data and constructs content (humanly doable? javascript isn't my strong point, but doesn't sound too bad and might even be more practical than php?)

3) something else?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: You should consider using AJAX for this. So, when the button is clicked (i assume you want to call the function when a button is clicked because of your function's name), you can perform an AJAX call and ask the server about the code that you need. Once you get the response, you insert it on the container node.

Comment: Yes, but who does the "encoding" of the html displayed? 1) the php called in the ajax returns html code already processed, and the javascript just thrown that in the div as-is, or, 2) the php just returns the database data needed, and the javascript preocesses this data returned and constructs the html code itself?

Comment: The "good practices" talks about separating the logic between the controller and the view so, in this case, i would say that it is better for you to serve just the data from the server (a JSON object, for instance) and handle it on browser's side. You have to take into account, with this approach, that browser's side processing will perform based on user's pc speed (but if your amount of data isn't really huge, it should not matter too much)

Answer (score 2):

It is usually a safe bet to follow the recommended best practices and separate logic from presentation. What does this would mean exactly?

In your case it could mean to

(1) use PHP to return the simple data in JSON format (i.e. involving only business logic on this side of your application). And

(2) Use a JavaScript template engine (Mustache, Handlebars, Underscore) in the front-end to display the received data as you would like.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Like milenvoutchev said, keep things separate like logic and presentation.

If you want to use template frameworks like handlebars, etc, by all means do so.

My approach is slightly different. I would use AJAX to retrieve the data from the database. This can be executed by clicking a link or any event listener. Meaning, create your PHP script in a separate file and have javascript (AJAX) access the php script, which would then access the database.

Then display the information retrieved from the database on the page through the AJAX call using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

although i did not get what you want probably its my language however 
if you mean

1-updating content of a div when event  happens like click you wanna get data form database then display it in the div of things like that ajax is the best way to do id which is combination between javascript and php you make an http request with javascript then the php file will send back the data back to javascript then you can do whatever is needed

2- if you mean creating html elements it depends really for example if the data you wanna load into the div is simple data and not that important and have nothing to do with server will javascript is good but other than that its better to use php to echo tags to your DOM

hope that was useful to you